# Javafx css achieve this sort of effect on text

Tags: css, javafx-2

I am trying to style some text in my Javafx application by making use of css. The effect I am trying to achieve is something like this:

[image]

I have the font, but it is just the effect that I am missing. This is what my `.css` file contains for the text.

```
.progress-view .title {
    -fx-font-family: "Bilbo Swash Caps";
    -fx-font-size: 34px;
    -fx-text-fill: white;
    -fx-blend-mode: darken;
    -fx-opacity: 0.8;
    -fx-effect: innershadow(gaussian , rgba(0,0,0,0.2),6,0.0,0,2);
}
```

The effect I have does not look remotely close to this. Also is this achievable by manipulating the effect or something else?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the following I seem to have gotten the text to look like the second one (bottom) which is good enough for me:

```
.progress-view .title {
    -fx-font: 60px "Bilbo Swash Caps";
    -fx-fill: white;
    -fx-stroke: black;
    -fx-stroke-width: 2;
    -fx-blend-mode: darken;
}
```

Would like to see that smokey effect of the other one though, so post any solutions you found. Thanks!